# Using translate.google from code

Tags: c#, url, webclient

Is there a way to use https://translate.google.co.za/ in code?

Maybe make use of Encoding, WebClients and Uri's, but I'm not sure on the correct way to do this.

In code I can get the translate to language and translate from language as well as the content, but how can I incorporate those parameters into the url and then display the end result?

Please Help

**Code attempt:**

```
UnicodeEncoding tmpEncoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
string url = String.Format("http://translate.google.co.za/#{0}/{1}/{2}", languageFrom, languageTo, content);
WebClient tmpClient = new WebClient();
tmpClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
string result = tmpEncoding.GetString(tmpClient.DownloadData(url));
```

The result it gives me is a list of chinese or japanese characters. I dont know what I doing wrong. Maybe the Encoding?

Comment: Can you also post the output which you are getting and which input are you sending to google? This is too less information to make help you further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer courtesy of Rick Strahl's Web Log (http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/Aug/06/Translating-with-Google-Translate-without-API-and-C-Code)

Although I didnt use the JavaScriptSerializer it gave me what I wanted. In the form of (\"content\").

So just a bit of string manipulation and I'm golden.

**EDIT:**

---

I ended up using the Serializer as the other way didn't give the special characters that form some words, i.e words from french woudnt have those characters that make the words frenchy. Instead it would give a question mark surrounded by a white diamond.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following website [click here](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs)
You can use the official Google Translate API for this

Take note that it will cost money to translate. Also take a look at other translate api which can be used inside .net

I Did some searching for ya, [Bing translator service](http://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/microsofttranslator) is a free API for a maximum of 2M characters a monthe from there on you have to pay for it. It also has a nice SDK to go with it.

Comment: Yeah, they work well, but I dont want to use API Keys.

Comment: Why don't you want to use ApiKeys if i may ask?

Comment: The application I am making is part of my training from my manager. He straight out said no ApiKeys.

Comment: If it was a normal application for my own benefit I would use ApiKeys, It makes things easier that way.

Comment: @LukeHolmwood: So it's a training task to see how well you can parse output of HTML pages? Might as well mention it in your question.

Comment: Azure Translator Text API URL is https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/cognitive-services/translator-text-api/ ,  Bing translator Web is https://www.bing.com/translator